# React Router: Handling queries through React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, currently, I have a routing component:

```
<Route path="/lists/:query" component={Lists} />
```

I get a call like:

```
http://localhost:4567/lists/page=17&city_codes=2567
```

In my `Lists` component, I handle this query in this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const query = match.params.query;
  const cleanQueryString = query.replace(/[|;$%@"<>()+,]/g, '');
  // break up the string using '&' and '=' into an object
  const properties = this.queryURL(cleanQueryString);
  const cleanQueryObj = _.pick(Object.assign({}, ...properties), [
  'page',
  'city_codes',
  'min_monthly_fee',
  'max_monthly_fee',
  'order_by',
]);

  // update the query object based on component state
  this.setState({ query: cleanQueryObj }, () => {
    cleanQueryObj.page && this.updateIndex(parseInt(cleanQueryObj.page, 10));
  });
  // call axios request and update redux
  dispatch(handleLists(cleanQueryObj));
  // update browser url
  this.props.history.push(cleanQueryObj);
```

Now, I see a lot of major sites using `?q=` before the query and I'm wondering what I'm missing or what could be improved?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you are doing is technically valid, it is a bit non-standard. The way you use the router `:query` param and the way it is formatted, reaaaaly looks like an actual `location.search` parameter format, and not a path parameter.

A more standard way to do it, would be with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4567/lists?page=17&city_codes=2567
```

And code as follow:

```
// In your routes, just a simple route with no path params
<Route path="/lists" component={Lists} />

// In your component
import queryString from 'query-string'

[...]

componentDidMount() {
  // Use location object from react-router
  const { search } = this.props.location 
  // Parse it using a npm dedicated module
  const { page, city_codes } = queryString.parse(search)
  // Now you can use those params
]);
```

Edit: and now an actual answer to the question:

`?q=blah` is usually used in a search context, with `q` parameter being a string used to search something. There can be other parameters following for example `?q=blah&ext=txt`.

It is hence different from your `:query` path param, which is encoded to contain multiple parameters, while `q` here is a single ready-to-use parameter.